# Strapi custom service overwrite find method

Tags: strapi

I'm using strapi v4 and I want to populate all nested fields by default when I retrieve a list of my objects (contact-infos). Therefore I have overwritten the contact-info service with following code:

```
export default factories.createCoreService('api::contact-info.contact-info', ({ strapi }): {} =>  ({
  async find(...args) {
    let { results, pagination } = await super.find(...args)
    results = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::contact-info.contact-info', {
      fields: ['locale'],
      populate: {
        sections: {
          populate: { link: true }
        }
      }
    })
    return { results, pagination }
  },
}));
```

That works well, but I execute a find all entries on the database twice, I guess, which I want to avoid, but when I try to return the result from the entityService directly I'm getting following response:

```
data": null,
"error": {
  "status": 404,
  "name": "NotFoundError",
  "message": "Not Found",
  "details": {}
}
```

also, I have no idea how I would retrieve the pagination information if I don't call `super.find()`. Is there any way to find all contents with the option to populate nested objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the recommended way of doing this, would be a middleware (do it once apply for all controllers). There would be an video `Best Practice Session 003` where  it's describes exactly this scenario (Not sure if it's discord only, but on moment of writing this it wasn't yet published).

So regarding rest of your question:

```
async find(...args) {
    let { results, pagination } = await super.find({...args, populate: {section: ['link']})
}
```

should be sufficient to fix that up in one query

custom pagination example:

```
async findOne(ctx) {
      const { user, auth } = ctx.state;
      const { id } = ctx.params;

      const limit = ctx.query?.limit ?? 20;
      const offset = ctx.query?.offset ?? 0;

      const logs = await strapi.db.query("api::tasks-log.tasks-log").findMany({
        where: { task: id },
        limit,
        offset,
        orderBy: { updatedAt: "DESC" },
      });

      const total = await strapi.db
        .query("api::tasks-log.tasks-log")
        .count({ where: { task: id } });

      return { data: logs, meta: { total, offset, limit } };
}
```

Comment: that works well, thanks. I can't find the video that explains how to implement the middleware though. Could you share a link or something?

Comment: @lando sorry but, seems it haven’t been uploaded just yet :(, you will be able to find it in Strapi Discord, on channel Best-Practices-Archive

Comment: there are just two videos :( 001 - entity service and 002 - populating relations, but anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: @lando https://youtu.be/YIbhKm1o0fE

Answer (score 0):

one small addition to the accepted answer, the answer didn't work completely since args is an array with an object inside, so I had to do it like this:

```
async find(...args) {
    const argsObj = args[0]
    let { results, pagination } = await super.find({...argsObj, populate: {section: ['link']})
}
```