# Strapi Generic filtering from REST request to EntityServiceAPI

Tags: strapi

I've been reading the docs on the EntityService API and I understand you can builder filters, populates etc, however I'm not sure how to pass the filters down from the request without parsing the URL manually and constructing an object?

If I have a GET request that looks like http://localhost:1337/my-content-types?filters[id][$eq]=1 which is how it looks in the filtering example here: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/filtering-locale-publication.html#deep-filtering

how do I pass the filters down to the EntityServiceAPI?

Request: `http://localhost:1337/my-content-types?filters[id][$eq]=1`

I have a core service that looks like this:

```
module.exports = createCoreService('plugin::my-plugin.my-content-type', ({strapi}) => ({
  find(ctx) {
    // console.log("Params:");
    return super.find(ctx)
  }
}))
```

which is called from the controller:

```
module.exports = createCoreController('plugin::my-plugin.my-content-type', ({strapi}) => ({
  async find(ctx) {
    return strapi
      .plugin(_pluginName)
      .service(_serviceName)
      .find(ctx);
  }
}));
```

and my routing:

```
module.exports = {
  type: 'admin',
  routes: [
    {
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/',
      handler: 'my-content-type.find',
      config: {
        policies: [],
        auth: false
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

**EDIT:**

I've got something working by writing my own very crude pagination, but I'm not happy with it, I'd really like a cleaner solution:

```
find(ctx) {
    const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(ctx.req._parsedUrl.search);
    const params = {
      start: urlSearchParams.get('start') || 0,
      limit: urlSearchParams.get('limit') || 25,
      populate: '*'
    }

    const results = strapi.entityService.findMany('plugin::my-plugin.my-content-type', params);
    return results;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get params from `ctx.query`

example:

```
async find(ctx){

  const limit = ctx.query?.limit ?? 20;
  const offset = ctx.query?.offset ?? 0;

  return await strapi.db.query('api::example.example').find({…ctx.query, limit, offset, populate: ['someRelation']});
}
```

I think the normally it done by wrapping `id` under where, and extracting the known parms. Gonna do a test when near pc but if the above variant dose not work, you can do the same with:

```
const { offset, limit, populate, …where} = ctx.query;

await strapi.db.query(‘…’).find({offset, limit, populate, where})
```

You can check pagination example in this thread: [Strapi custom service overwrite find method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74659040/strapi-custom-service-overwrite-find-method/74665256#74665256)